# Adding Sound effects in JavaScript / HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project for Table football. Where i need to add sound effects based on interrupts.

For e.g. Goal Scored = It's a Goal 
If Black Team wins, it should shout Team Black Congratulations, you won 
If Green Team wins, it should shout Team Green Congratulations, you won

Comment: Add your code! It's the only way we can help!!

Comment: What is your specific question about programming?

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure what you are trying to ask, but to add sounds you can

1) Record the sounds first and save them
2) Play the respective audio according to your condition

EXAMPLE :

We have 2 sound files : 
1) blackteamwon.mp4 (which has sound "Team Black Congratulations, you won ") 
2) greenteamwon.mp4 (which has sound "Team Green Congratulations, you won ")

HTML

```
<span id="sound"></span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function playSound(soundfile){
    document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML="<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\"/>";
}

if(blackteamgoals){// Your condition
    playSound("blackteamwon.mp3"); // Location to your sound file
}

if(greenteamgoals){// Your condition
    playSound("greenteamwon.mp3"); // Location to your sound file
}
```